# Page reloads constantly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, in Firefox only, our page keeps reloading continuously. There seems to be no explanation for this. (Happens in FF19.0 on both Mac and PC)

I've been slaving away for hours trying to fix this problem. I tried making the page (mostly) validate in W3C but that did not work either. I tried removing all the Facebook API code as well, but to no avail.

You can see the page here: 
http://www.socialgoodnetwork.com/home.php

With no Facebook code:
http://www.socialgoodnetwork.com/home.php?fb=1

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Doesn't reload in FF19 here. Perhaps a browser addon you have installed is causing it?

Comment: We've tried in on two different computers plus one of our clients experienced it. Perhaps try refreshing once to see if it happens.

Comment: I can confirm this happens on my FF. My guess would be http://www.socialgoodnetwork.com/scripts/frame_buster.js

Comment: Hmmm, it does seem to reload a couple of times, but not continually. Only thing I can see is that it always seems to stop when your `primer-view-count` cookie is a multiple of 4 - you're not doing something strange with that are you?

Comment: No, I only check if it's nonzero. Also, on our end, it refreshes a lot more than four times.

Comment: It is refreshing constantly in every browser except for Chrome for me. (FF 19.0, Seamonkey 2.16, IE 8, Chrome 25.0.1364.152). I am seeing a message in my console that reads: getLoginStatus - unknown !ready_to_accept_login !was_not_authorized +is_appropriate_to_refresh. That seems a bit suspect.

Comment: I disabled frame_buster.js so if the issue doesn't happen, we know that that was the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a framebuster.js which reloads the page when there are any frames present the dom....and you seem to have a lot of iframes - facebook might be one but also youtube and some written out by javascript...

Comment: I can't believe that was it. Nice work!

Comment: How did you find that?

Comment: View source and look for reload...